# Why doesn't the IR module lirc_ene0100 exist in kernel 2.6.36?

Tags: kernel, modules

I have an IR controller that uses the kernel module lirc_ene0100. I can load it with kernel 2.6.35 but it doesn't exist in 2.6.36 and 2.6.37-rc1.

Answer (score 1):

See: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/116190/

I honestly can't say what's going on there but it *seems* (to an ignoramus like myself) very relevant. If you can't make heads or tails from that either, you might do best to ask Maxim directly about the change.

Comment: Thanks. I email Maxim and here is his answer: " ene0100 will be replaced with ene_ir, a better driver that allows both
in-kernel decoding and lirc interface."